# Scikit-learn PCA forecasting time series; error with transform

Tags: scikit-learn, pca, array-broadcasting

I am attempting a multi-variate time series forecast using Principal Component Analysis and vector auto-regression.

My data is contained in a pandas dataframe with 4 variables of shape (14193, 4).

So, I have found the PCs, projected them forward using VAR, and now I am trying to convert these PCs back into my original 4 variables using the `.transform()` method, as per [this post on statsexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229092/how-to-reverse-pca-and-reconstruct-original-variables-from-several-principal-com)

I have the following code:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.var_model import VAR

# first PCA
df = df     #obviously not exact code; shown for completeness)
pca = PCA(n_components=3, copy=True, whiten=False)
pca.fit(df)
dpca = pd.DataFrame(pca.transform(df))     #dataframe of 3 component values for each historical data point

# now VAR
model = VAR(dpca)
model_fit = model.fit()
yhat = model_fit.forecast(model_fit.y, steps=10)
```

This works perfectly and provides `(10,3)` output of projected PCs. Now, I want to take the yhat values for the PCs and convert back to the original variables. However, when I do this:

```
mu = np.mean(dpca, axis=0)
new_vars = np.dot(pca.transform(yhat), pca.components_)
new_vars += mu
```

I receive the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,3) (4,)
```

It fails on the line `pca.transform(yhat)` and specifically on `X = X - self.mean_`. So clearly the "mean" referred to is of shape `(4,)`.

I guess my question is, how do I perform the transform so that it incorporates my new `dpca` dataset based on the PCs, which has a mean shape of `(3,)`

Comment: `pca.inverse_transform(yhat)` should return `yhat` in the original 4 variables.

Comment: it does! thx very much